# python 2.7- django 1.7 (virtualenv) AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet error

Tags: django, python-2.7, authentication

I am trying to call `User.objects.get(pk=1)`, but I am getting this error message:

`File "C:\Project\Project\env\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 131, in check_models_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Models aren't loaded yet.")
AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.`

I am able to call `User.objects.all()` successfully.

What's missing? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am answering my own question. I had to call django.setup() in the interactive Python shell.

```
import django
django.setup()
```